# VsCode doesn't show intellisense for electron module

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

When I type console. it shows every method and when using the methods it shows their respective information, same with path module, but anything related to electron is 'any'

[image: vsc shows 'any' for all methods and types from electron, but works on console. and path module]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behaviour. Can you share some steps to reproduce? How are you importing electron for example?

Comment: Don't really know how to reproduce, it just.. doesn't, it's the same if do require or import